# How to use nunique in a condition for comparing the number of unique values in a dataset to a math expression

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a method to determine the minimum and maximum frequencies for a dataset. The method `nunique()` returns the count of distinct values for the data, but it the expected result is not returned. My goal is:

*Determine the number of distinct values within the attribute of Class in the partition is Floor(n/2), where n is the number of distinct values in the original dataset.*

For example,

Sample input data

```
A1,A2,A3,Class
2,0.4631338,1.5,3
8,0.7460648,3.0,3
6,0.264391038,2.5,2
5,0.4406713,2.3,1
2,0.410438159,1.5,3
2,0.302901816,1.5,2
6,0.275869396,2.5,3
8,0.084782428,3.0,3
2,0.53226533,1.5,2
8,0.070034818,2.9,1
2,0.668631847,1.5,2
```

Expected:
`(s_temp.nunique()['A1'] == floor(n/2))` checks that the number of distinct values within the attribute of Class in the partition is Floor(n/2).

Actual:

```
File "assignment_1.py", line 18, in main
    s = entropy_discretization(s)
  File "assignment_1.py", line 78, in entropy_discretization
    if (maxf(s1)/minf(s1) < 0.5) and (s_temp.nunique()['A1'] == floor(n/2)):
  File "C:\Users\physe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1330, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've written a program to process the dataset

```
def main():
    s = pd.read_csv('A1-dm.csv')
    print("******************************************************")
    print("Entropy Discretization                         STARTED")
    s = entropy_discretization(s)
    print("Entropy Discretization                         COMPLETED")

def entropy_discretization(s):

    I = {}
    i = 0
    n = s.nunique()['A1']
    s_temp = s
    s1 = pd.DataFrame()
    s2 = pd.DataFrame()
    while(uniqueValue(s_temp)):
        

        # Step 1: pick a threshold
        threshold = s_temp['A1'].iloc[0]

        # Step 2: Partititon the data set into two parttitions
        s1 = s[s['A1'] < threshold]
        print("s1 after spitting")
        print(s1)
        print("******************")
        s2 = s[s['A1'] >= threshold]
        print("s2 after spitting")
        print(s2)
        print("******************")

        print("******************")
        print("calculating maxf")
        maxf(s['A1'])
        print("******************")

        # print(maxf(s['A1'])/minf(s['A1']))
        if (maxf(s1)/minf(s1) < 0.5) and (s_temp.nunique()['A1'] == floor(n/2)):
            break
            
        # Step 3: calculate the information gain.
        informationGain = information_gain(s1,s2,s_temp)
        I.update({f'informationGain_{i}':informationGain,f'threshold_{i}': threshold})
        print(f'added informationGain_{i}: {informationGain}, threshold_{i}: {threshold}')
        s_temp = s_temp[s_temp['A1'] != threshold]
        i += 1

    # Step 5: calculate the min information gain
    n = int(((len(I)/2)-1))
    print("Calculating maximum threshold")
    print("*****************************")
    maxInformationGain = 0
    maxThreshold       = 0 
    for i in range(0, n):
        if(I[f'informationGain_{i}'] > maxInformationGain):
            maxInformationGain = I[f'informationGain_{i}']
            maxThreshold       = I[f'threshold_{i}']

    print(f'maxThreshold: {maxThreshold}, maxInformationGain: {maxInformationGain}')
    # replace all values in s1 with 1
    print(s1)
    print('***********************************')
    # replace all values in s2 with 2
    print(s2)

    # Step 6: keep the partitions of S based on the value of threshold_i
    return s #maxPartition(maxInformationGain,maxThreshold,s,s1,s2)


def maxf(s):
    return s.max()

def minf(s):
    return s.min()

def uniqueValue(s):
    # are records in s the same? return true
    if s.nunique()['A1'] == 1:
        return False
    # otherwise false 
    else:
        return True

def maxPartition(maxInformationGain,maxThreshold,s,s1,s2):
    print(f'informationGain: {maxInformationGain}, threshold: {maxThreshold}')
    merged_partitions =  pd.merge(s1,s2)
    merged_partitions =  pd.merge(merged_partitions,s)
    print("Best Partition")
    print("***************")
    print(merged_partitions)
    print("***************")
    return merged_partitions




def information_gain(s1, s2, s):
    # calculate cardinality for s1
    cardinalityS1 = len(pd.Index(s1['A1']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s1 is: {cardinalityS1}')
    # calculate cardinality for s2
    cardinalityS2 = len(pd.Index(s2['A1']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s2 is: {cardinalityS2}')
    # calculate cardinality of s
    cardinalityS = len(pd.Index(s['A1']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s is: {cardinalityS}')
    # calculate informationGain
    informationGain = (cardinalityS1/cardinalityS) * entropy(s1) + (cardinalityS2/cardinalityS) * entropy(s2)
    print(f'The total informationGain is: {informationGain}')
    return informationGain



def entropy(s):
    print("calculating the entropy for s")
    print("*****************************")
    print(s)
    print("*****************************")

    # initialize ent
    ent = 0

    # calculate the number of classes in s
    numberOfClasses = s['Class'].nunique()
    print(f'Number of classes for dataset: {numberOfClasses}')
    value_counts = s['Class'].value_counts()
    p = []
    for i in range(0,numberOfClasses):
        n = s['Class'].count()
        # calculate the frequency of class_i in S1
        print(f'p{i} {value_counts.iloc[i]}/{n}')
        f = value_counts.iloc[i]
        pi = f/n
        p.append(pi)
    
    print(p)

    for pi in p:
        ent += -pi*log2(pi)

    return ent

main()
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error in the line: `if (maxf(s1)/minf(s1) < 0.5) and (s_temp.nunique()['A1'] == floor(n/2)):` because s1 is a dataframe with multiple columns, your max function returns multiple values. Therefore the error you receive says: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

If you select the column in the dataframe you want the max value for, the error disappears. See the example below:

```
# print(maxf(s['A1'])/minf(s['A1']))
if (maxf(s1['A1'])/minf(s1['A1']) < 0.5) and (s_temp.nunique()['A1'] == floor(n/2)):
   break
```

Also your example code misses the flowing import statements:

```
import pandas as pd
from math import pi, floor, log2
```